# Flickering MapOverlay after zoom out and zoom in-iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios6, mkmapview

I have two questions. First of all, once I allocate memory for the coordinates please see the code below, do I have to free memory free(coords)? Second, as you seen below code, I get overlay and add on the map. However, there is a different timestamps feeds coordinates and should update map. Like a radar map changing overlay shape with different time stamps.It is updating very well initially; however, once user zoom out and zoom in, it starts flashing or flickering. I wonder why this flickering happens? Anybody has experienced that problem before?

```
NSArray *ants = [mapView overlays];
for(bb = 0; bb < [polygonArray count]; bb++){
        int attr=[[idArray objectAtIndex:bb]floatValue];


        coords = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb] count]);
        for (int a = 0;a < [[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb] count]; a++){
            coords[a].latitude = [[[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]objectAtIndex:a]objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
            coords[a].longitude = [[[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]objectAtIndex:a]objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
        }
        polygon = [[MKPolygon alloc]init];
        polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coords count:[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]count]]; 
        //free(coords);
        [previousPolygons addObject:polygon];

            }
        [mapView addOverlay:polygon];
        }

    }
[mapView removeOverlays:ants];
```

Comment: yes you need to free the memory you malloced, but you shouldn't be asking the same question twice on SO or asking two questions on one page because you might get an answer for each and you can only mark one as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Apples

> [BreadCrumbs Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html)

App.
Using this Demo you see the recommended technic to do your task.
I have used that Demo in my App, and it worked like a charm.

The approach with MkPolygon does not work fine withn big polygons, or changing Polygons.

Comment: I have tested my code posted above with iphone 4s it did not flick, once I tested with iphone 5 it flicker because of processor speed. I dont know how to prevent this flickering! Do you think if I implement BreadCrumb example, my problem goes away?

Comment: Try out the breadcrumb demo, at iphone 5, and look yourself. I believe yes, that will be a good idea to use the technic in breadcrumbs

Comment: Ah now i see, with Mkpolygon it will not work, that will flicker!

Comment: Thank  Alex, what should I use then?

Comment: and also, why flickers with MKPolygon?

Comment: If you have hundreds or thousands of polygon point in th epoly line, the technic with crumbs demo is much better. If you only want to draw a poly line with a few points, MKPolygon might be suffcient. MKPolygon or more exatlcy MkMapView  is not well suited for dynmically adding and deleteing MkPolygons, that will flicker in any case. There are other known bugs in Overlays, like not dispalying some elements.

Comment: Hello Alex, could you please take a look at my app please. that would give you better idea.. thanks a lot in advance..https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ozonemap/id579938656?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: I have it , but did not found a date where ozon is visible, but as i see, you want to draw filled polygons which change dynamically. My experience us that adding and removing annotation views, is flicker prone. I suggest do further research of flickering, or try out the crumbs demo approach which i higliy expect that it would work better.

Comment: By the way, your app is restriczed to ios6, it did not work on my iphone. (I used it on ipad)

Comment: I just clicked on your answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have tested BreadCrumbs Demo on iOS 6.1 (iPad 3) and it flicker. It's a bug of the new MKMapView (sad). I have submitted the bug to Apple.

Comment: We also have this issue. To check we have the same issue: We have noticed that the screen flickers (redraws) when adding an overlay to MKMapView, whether we add a MKPolygon or our own polygon overlay. 
We have also noticed that it happens only on iPads with retina display and between zoom level N.0001 to N.5 (No problem between N.5 to N.0). 
Do you have a link to you issue on the issue tracker so that we can +1 it ?

Comment: In our case it happens both with iOS 5.1 and 6.1.

Comment: I've got the same problem - flicker starts at a certain zoom level, before that - no problem. 
On my iPhone6 running iOS 8.3 I have no problem, on my iPad Mini 1 running iOS 8.3 it flickers.
Anyone found a solution?