# Custom uipicker- dealing with image size

Tags: ios, uipicker

[image]

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
           viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
         forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //NSLog(@"%d",component);
   // NSLog(@"tag: %d",pickerView.tag);

    if([pickerView isEqual:picker1])

    {


        NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+1];
        NSArray *array1 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
        if ([pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) {
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(60,60,40,80);//set bigger frame
        } else {
            //imageView.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,20,60);//set normal frame
        }
        return imageView;
        }

}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 80.0;

}
```

I am implementing custom uipicker to achieve the first following image. I have three images to be chosen with uipicker. However, all of them are shown on the screen in the second image below. I want only in middle shown occupy bigger size rather than other images as shown  image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post any code and what is the exact issue when you are setting the frame for those images?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548055/custom-uipicker

Comment: What is happening when you set frame for `barView` as `barView.frame = CGRectMake(...` ? You need to set a bigger frame for only middle one.

Comment: How? Could you give a hint, please? or any resources?

Comment: `UIImageView *barView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bar];` `barView.frame = CGRectMake(.. //set frame here`

Comment: in which method in my code?

Comment: and also how to disable/hide blue rectangle as it comes default?

Comment: Check my answer. You have to set `showsSelectionIndicator` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As per your comment, you need to make the middle row to be bigger one.

Modify your viewForRow method as,

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
           viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
         forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //NSLog(@"%d",component);
    NSLog(@"tag: %d",pickerView.tag);

    if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {   NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+1];
        NSArray *array1 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
        if ([pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) {
           imageView.frame = CGRectMake(..);//set bigger frame
        } else {
           imageView.frame = CGRectMake(..);//set normal frame
        }
        return imageView;
    }
```

Implement `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` method and set suitable height for rows.

```
    - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
```

In order to hide the Selection Indicator, set `showsSelectionIndicator` property of `UIPickerView`. For more details [check apple doc.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPickerView/showsSelectionIndicator)

Based on your comment,

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
      [pickerView reloadComponent:component];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution with code, appreciated. However, once I implemented it does not give me exact solution that I want. What I want is chosen part would be more dominant than others. Please see my updated screenshot above.

Comment: also once you make imagesize bigger, than two images are overlapping.

Comment: I think, I misunderstood your question. By middle, I assumed it as middle pickerview. In that case you need to set the frame in pickerview delegate method.

Comment: How should I do? I would be very appreciated if you could give me in detail answer, please?

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving such a fabolus answer with code. I am very impressed. I have just attached latest screenshot above, once another image comes to middle, it does not get bigger size. Could u please guide me?

Comment: @user1724168, Is the above method getting called when scrolling occurs?

Comment: @user1724168, is going inside this if condition `if ([pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) {`?

Comment: Once it initalize images in uipicker, it goes into that code. However, once I scroll picker, it does not go into that code!

Comment: @user1724168, So is it calling the delegate method while scrolling? If yes, can you try printing `[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component]`  in an NSLog and check what is the value of that while scrolling in that delegate method? Is it same as row or not?

Comment: no it is not calling that delegate method while I am scrolling.

Comment: @user1724168, In that case try implementing `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` method and see if that is getting called while scrolling. If yes, do this in that `[pickerView reloadComponent:component];`

Comment: could you give me a small portion of code please to see the clear picture? sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @user1724168, Check the answer. Is it calling the above `didSelectRow` method while scrolling? If yes, check if the above fixes your issue.

Comment: cool. now scrolling image getting bigger. However, once I scroll back, it is not getting back to normal size!

Comment: @user1724168, Is it calling the else part  `else {
           imageView.frame = CGRectMake(..);//set normal frame
        }` for the other rows?

Comment: My fault, sorry. It works flawlessly :-) thanks a lot. owe u a starbucks coffee but dont know how to deliver !! :-)

Comment: I have one bounty question, if you know any idea, you're welcome!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364758/flickering-mapoverlay-after-zoom-out-and-zoom-in-ios

Comment: I will check it later. Looks like Alex has already answered it. What was the issue with his code?

Comment: it flickers. I have tested with iphone 4s it did not flick, once I tested with iphone 5 it flicker because of processor speed. I dont know how to prevent this flickering!

Answer (score 0):

whomever needs to help! Here is the solution. All Credits go to @ACB!!!

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
               viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
             forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
    {
        //NSLog(@"%d",component);
       // NSLog(@"tag: %d",pickerView.tag);

        if(pickerView.tag==1)

        {


            NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+1];
            NSArray *array1 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
            if ([pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(60,60,40,80);//set bigger frame
            } else {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,20,60);//set normal frame
            }
            return imageView;

            //NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+1];
            //NSArray *array1 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
            //return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else if([pickerView isEqual:picker2])
        {
            NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+5];
            NSArray *array1 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
            if ([pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(60,60,40,80);//set bigger frame
            } else {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,20,60);//set normal frame
            }
            return imageView;


            /* NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+5];
            NSArray *array2 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
            return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];*/
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+9];
            NSArray *array1 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
            if ([pickerView selectedRowInComponent:component] == row) {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(60,60,40,80);//set bigger frame
            } else {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,20,60);//set normal frame
            }
            return imageView;



           /* NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",component+9];
            NSArray *array3 = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
            return [array3 objectAtIndex:row];*/
        }

    }

    - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        return 120.0;

    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        [pickerView reloadComponent:component];
    }
```